# How do I render partials with jade without express.js?

Tags: node.js, templating, pug

Only info I found was this:

http://forrst.com/posts/Node_js_Jade_Import_Jade_File-CZW

I replicated the suggested folder structure (views/partials) But it didn't work, as soon as I put

```
!=partial('header', {})
!=partial('menu', {})
```

into index.jade, I get a blank screen, the error message I receive from jade is:

> ReferenceError: ./views/index.jade:3
>       1. 'p index'
>       2. ''
>       3. '!=partial(\'header', {})'
>
> partial is not defined

I'd be very grateful for any help ! (I strongly prefer not to use express.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think partial rendering is done in express, so you will have to snag that code or write your own.

I have my own helper class for jade rendering with partials that you can use or get some ideas from [here](https://gist.github.com/938647), (it's using [Joose](http://joose.it) and [Cactus](https://github.com/Raevel/Cactus))

Comment: Hi Adam, What's the way to use the code you linked? Looks like it might be the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 23):

Jade has a command called include. Just use

```
include _form
```

given that the filename of the partial is *_form.jade*, and is in the same directory

Comment: include works most of the time but can't do things like recursive inclusion as they're included at compile time.

Comment: wouldn't you simply perform the recursion in the include?

Answer (score 9):

As of August 2012 (possibly earlier) Partials have been removed from Express.

A lot of tutorials are now out of date. It seems that you can replicate much of the partial functionality with include.

Eg.

movies.jade

```
div(id='movies')
  - each movie in movies
    include movie
```

movie.jade

```
h2= movie.title
.description= movie.description
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

With the latest node/express I get the following movies.jade template to call partials:

```
div(id='movies')
  - each movie in movies
    !=partial('movie', movie)
```

where I have movie.jade in the views directory alongside movies.jade.

movies.jade is called from app.js with:

`res.render('movies', { movies: [{ title: 'Jaws' }, { title: 'Un Chien Andalou' }] });`