# Node.js - How to use jade partials with express.js (2.5.8)

Tags: node.js, express, partial-views, pug

I am posting this questions after reading this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764693/how-do-i-render-partials-with-jade-without-express-js)

I have a node.js app running which uses Express 2.5.8 and Jade 0.26.0

I have a jade page that will consist of many widgets. On scouring the internet it seemed ideal to use partials to modularize these widgets.

So my jade main page called comp.jade is

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
head
  body
    h2.page-header REPORT FOR #{comp_name}
    .other_ds
      partial('partials/ln_profile')
```

And my ln_profile.jade is

```
p.ln_profile
    strong  #{comp_ln_name}  
      br
      | #{comp_description}
```

On the server side my script looks like

```
res.render('comp',{comp_name: 'Some Company'}); // to pass data to comp.jade
res.partial( 'partials/ln_profile',{comp_ln_name: 'Test Company',comp_description:'Test Description'});  // to pass data to ln_profile.jade
```

But when I do this only ln_profile.jade gets rendered and the comp.jade is not getting rendered.

Where am I going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Partials is deprecated. You have to use Include statement instead of partials.